# Mockito test simulate so that first 2 retry attempt fails and 3rd one succeeds

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Below is a piece of code which is retrying a DB operation. I am using Spring Retrytemplate to retry for 3 times at 2sec intervals. However, I would like to know how to simulate so that first 2 attempts fail and 3rd one succeeds in my Mockito unit test.

Code block under test:

```
Stream<ClassResult> result = retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
            Stream<ClassResult> results = dbHelper.createProducts(products);
            log.info(logger, String.format("Success on retry attempt: %s", context.getRetryCount()));
            return results;
        }, (recovery) -> {
            log.error(logger, "Fail! All retries exhausted.", new Exception(recovery.getLastThrowable().getMessage()));
            return null;
        });
```

Mockito tests:

1. This gives me ClassCastException saying RunTimeException cant be cast to Stream

```
when(retryTemplate.execute(any(), any(), any()))
.thenReturn(new RuntimeException("Error")) //fail 1st attempt
.thenReturn(new RuntimeException("Error")) //fail 2nd attempt

.thenReturn(Stream.of(new ClassResult("some Data"))) //pass 3rd attempt
```

2. Tried with Mockito.thenAnswer but got same result.

Comment: Try using thenThrow instead of thenReturn. The method would not return an exception (probably, unless ClassResult extends Exception) on error, it would throw it.

Comment: Also, I think you'd want to be stubbing the createProducts call on dbHelper instead of execute()

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns a `Stream`, as such you cannot return an `RuntimeException`. Exceptions are (usually) not returned by methods, but *thrown*. Mockito can [stub a method to throw](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing) an exception instead of returning a value.

It's also important to note that it is not the retry template that's throwing the exception, but the actual operation that should be retried (i.e. `createProducts`):

```
when(dbHelper.createProducts(anyCollection()))
    .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Error")) //fail 1st attempt
    .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Error")) //fail 2nd attempt
    .thenReturn(Stream.of(new ClassResult("some Data"))) //pass 3rd attempt
```